# How to use intent inside custom BaseAdapter

Tags: android, listview, android-intent

I have 2 activities- MainActivity & ListresultActivity. In the ListresultActivity i used a custom adapter for listView. But for each row in the list i have a button which i want to use to go back to the MainActivity using intent. How am i going to use setResult(RESULT_OK,intnt) and finish() inside the onclick?

Here is the code:
**MainActivity:**

```
int request_code = 1
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)     
{         
    if (requestCode == request_code) 
    {  if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) 
       { //Toast. makeText(this,data.getData().toString(),  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Student aStu = (Student)data.getSerializableExtra("studentObj");

       }        
    }    
}
```

**ListResultActivity**(2nd Activity, where i am using a listview and my own sipleBaseAdapter custom class):

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
 SimpleBaseAdapter datatHolder = new SimpleBaseAdapter(this, studentList);
 myList.setAdapter(datatHolder);
}
```

**SimpleBaseAdapter class**(custom class for baseAdapter):

```
public class SimpleBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter 
{  @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) adapterContext
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_listrowitem, parent, false);

    Button btnBack = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.listRw_btnBk);
    final  Student student = studentDataHolder.get(position);
    if (student != null) {

      btnBack.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

  public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

Intent intnt = new Intent(adapterContext,MainActivity.class);
intnt.putExtra("studentObj", student);
//setResult(RESULT_OK, intnt);
//ListResultActivity.this.finish();
}
});
    }
    return rowView;

}
```

Comment: using an intent with putExtra to manage conditions/pass data to the main activity is not an alternative for your implementation?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `setResult` same way as you are doing right now, But for finishing activity, use following line:-

`((Activity)adapterContext).finish();`

Here, I've assumed that `adapterContext` is the `Context` passed by `ListresultActivity` for which you have set adapter.

Comment: setResult(RESULT_OK, intnt); is showing error- either create local variable/consatnt/field/parameter

Comment: @user2751449 I think you have not created any variable named as `RESULT_OK`, either create one or try by replacing `RESULT_OK` with integer `1`. This might work.